# Login Identity - Not working in HttpContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My website uses " login form using IPrincipal and IIdentity .

The code can be seen below._iTs work Great

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Web;

namespace FREELANCER.Models
{
    public class UserPrincipal : IPrincipal
    {
        private LoginModel LoginInfo;
        private DemoUsers d = new DemoUsers();


        public UserPrincipal(LoginModel log)
        {
            LoginInfo = log;
            Identity = new GenericIdentity(log.Emailaddress);
        }

        public IIdentity Identity
        {
            get;
            private set;

        }

        public bool IsInRole(string role)
        {
            var roles = role.Split(new char[] { ',' });
            return roles.Any(r => this.LoginInfo.Roles.Contains(r));
        }
    }
}
```

But I can´t get this to work:

```
             string name = User.Identity.Name;
            string AuthenticationType = User.Identity.AuthenticationType;
            bool ss = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
            bool Inrole =User.IsInRole("Admin");
```

They are alway empty, Why ?

Is it true that the object of IPrincipal and IIdentity will Copied to HttpContext and is therefore available throughout the website?

```
NB: namespace FREELANCER.Security
{
    public class UserAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
    {

        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(SessionPersister.UserName))
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { Controller = "Login", Action = "Login" }));
            else
            {
                DemoUsers ds = new DemoUsers();
                UserPrincipal mp = new UserPrincipal(ds.FindUser(SessionPersister.UserName));

                if (!mp.IsInRole(Roles))
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { Controller = "AccessDenied", Action = "Index" }));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating the new **Principal** object, you also need to attach it to current **HttpContext** object.

```
UserPrincipal mp = new UserPrincipal(ds.FindUser(SessionPersister.UserName));
HttpContext.Current.User = mp;
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = mp;
```

Second line is option unless you decide to call **UserPrincipal** from current thread - `Thread.CurrentPrincipal as UserPrincipal`.

Comment: Do this mean, that I have to do this in LogOUT:

HttpContext.Current.User = null;
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = null;

?

Comment: No, you do not need to assign null for logout. By default `HttpContext.Current.User` is null on every request until you attach Principal object to it.